# 「行動規範」が記載されたページへ簡単にアクセスできるようにして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 行動規範

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

上のページにもっと簡単にアクセスできるようにして欲しいです。

現在このページは https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange にリストされていますが、[ヘルプセンターのトップページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)からはリンクされていません。

なのでまずは、ヘルプセンターのトップページ「弊社のモデル」のリストの上部に固定表示して欲しいです。

[image: 現状の「弊社のモデル」のスクリーンショットです。]

#### 関連

- 英語版 Stack Overflow やスペイン語版 Stack Overflow では、ヘルプセンターの「弊社のモデル」に表示されていました。

  - https://stackoverflow.com/help
  - https://es.stackoverflow.com/help
- 将来的には、トップバーのプルダウンメニューに追加して欲しいです。Meta Stack Exchange に同様の機能要求が出ていました。

  - [Adding Code of Conduct to Help pulldown on top bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313794/341401)

---

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Let us make the access to the page above (our Code of Conduct) more easily.

The Code of Conduct is currently listed on "Our model" https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange, but it is not linked from  Help Center https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help.

The first step we need to take is making a change so the Code of Conduct is displayed at the very top of the list of "Our model" https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange.

Comment: 私は記事を一番上にした。 質問に関連して何か他に何かする必要があるかどうか教えてください。

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 対応ありがとうございます。リンクのテキストを修正することはできますか？ / 「スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の行動規範」 → 「スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範」

Comment: @cubick できた！ あなたのために何か他のことができるかどうか教えてください！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicholas さんがヘルプセンターでの位置を[移動してくださいました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3033/%E8%A1%8C%E5%8B%95%E8%A6%8F%E7%AF%84-%E3%81%8C%E8%A8%98%E8%BC%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%B8%E7%B0%A1%E5%8D%98%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%AC%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%84?noredirect=1#comment2853_3033) :)

関連して提案したことはありますが、ひとまず要望していたことは実装されました。

Answer (score 3):

未登録ユーザがよくみる上のここにも「StackOverflowは次の行動規範を推奨しております。」みたいな
よさげな文言といっしょに設置したい感じもします！
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]