# 「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」の所属するカテゴリが「弊社のモデル」の理由とカテゴリ移動の提案

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, 完了

### 経緯

英語版の「[Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」カテゴリと、それに対応する日本語版の「[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」カテゴリを読み比べていました。
そのとき、「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」が、「[Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」カテゴリには存在し、「[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」カテゴリには存在しないことに気付きました。

---

### 疑問点と提案

「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」は、このページ冒頭にも書かれているとおり、コード上の問題について質問をする場合の参考ページとなっています。

> **コード上の問題について質問を投稿する場合**、同じ問題を手元で再現できるようなサンプルコードを提供すると、よりよい回答がもらえます。そのための「よいサンプルコード」といえるための条件がいくつかあります：

そのため、このページの内容は全体的に質問者へ向けたものとなっており、質問者が質問を投稿するときに読むであろう「[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」にあるほうが好ましいと思います。

そこで、質問と提案ですが、

1. 「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」の所属するカテゴリが「[弊社のモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)」である理由は何でしょうか？
2. また、上記の理由から、「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」を「[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」へ移動する (もしくはどちらにも載せる) ことを提案します。

---

### 関連する投稿

- [「行動規範」が記載されたページへ簡単にアクセスできるようにして欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3033/32986)
  英語版では「[弊社のモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)」に記載されており、日本語版ではどこにも記載されていないという点で、今回と類似していると考えたため、関連投稿として載せておきます。

また、英語版と日本語版でカテゴリの所属が異なるページは (どちらかのサイトに存在しないページを除けば) 、「[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)」と「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」のみのようです。

---

I would like to suggest to move the location of "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to "Asking" https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Currently it is located under "Our model" for some reason
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」が「[弊社のモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)」カテゴリから「[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」カテゴリへ移動されたことを確認しました。よって、そのスクリーンショットをもって、この質問を解決済みにしたいと思います。対応いただき、ありがとうございました。

[image: 赤点線部が新たに「質問にあたって」カテゴリに追加された項目]